# number of paths in a binary tree with a given sum

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am solving the problem https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-iii/
I'll also briefly mention it here:
Find the number of paths in a Binary tree whose sum = sum. The path does not necessarily have to begin (end) at the root (leaf). As long as the path goes downward it should be considered as a valid path.

Here is my solution:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */

public class Solution {
    public int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        int path = 0;
        if(root.val == sum)
            return 1;
        else if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
            return 0;
        if(root.left != null){
            path += pathSum(root.left, sum - root.val);
            path += pathSum(root.left, sum);
        }
        if(root.right != null){
            path += pathSum(root.right, sum - root.val);
            path += pathSum(root.right, sum);
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

The answer as per their system is 3, but I am getting the answer as 4 for the following input:

```
root = [10,5,-3,3,2,null,11,3,-2,null,1], sum = 8

      10
     /  \
    5   -3
   / \    \
  3   2   11
 / \   \
3  -2   1

Return 3. The paths that sum to 8 are:

1.  5 -> 3
2.  5 -> 2 -> 1
3. -3 -> 11
```

I have spent hours trying to reason why my code wold not work, but I cannot figure out the problem.

Sorry for a naive question :( But this is killing me!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what's wrong in your solution, but I don't think it's correct. For one thing, if your root was 8 you would immediately return and count only the root as solution. This is how I would do it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Solution {
    public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
      return pathSum(root, sum, 0, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum, int count, ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        arr.add(root.val);
        int acc = 0;
        for (int i=arr.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
          acc += arr.get(i);
          if (acc == sum)
            count++;
        }
        if(root.left != null)
            count = pathSum(root.left, sum, count, arr);
        if(root.right != null)
            count = pathSum(root.right, sum, count, arr);
        arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
        return count;
    }

  static class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode(int v) {
      this.val = v;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(10);
    root.left = new TreeNode(5);
    root.right = new TreeNode(-3);
    root.left.left = new TreeNode(3);
    root.left.right = new TreeNode(2);
    root.right.right = new TreeNode(11);
    root.left.left.left = new TreeNode(3);
    root.left.left.right = new TreeNode(-2);
    root.left.right.right = new TreeNode(1);
    System.out.println(pathSum(root, 8));
  }
}
```

The idea is to populate an aarray with the value along the path as you traverse the tree recursively, making sure you remove elements as you return. When you visit a node, you have to consider all the sums from that node to any node on the path to the root. Any of them can add up to your reference value. This implementation is O(nlogn), as you traverse n nodes, and for each you traverse an array of len up to log(n).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see the bug with immediately returning. :)

Answer (score 1):

your code cant satisfy this constraint:

```
these nodes should be continuous.
```

e.g the *root*(value 10) of this tree and the *leaf*(value -2) of this tree, the sum of them is equals 8. **but** it dont satisfy continous, so It cant count.

Unfortunately, your code cant filter this case.

an alternative Solution:

```
public class Solution {
public int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    int path = traverse(root,sum);
    return path;
}

public int traverse(TreeNode root, int sum){
    int path = 0;
    if(root==null){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        path += calcu(root,sum);
        path += traverse(root.left,sum);
        path += traverse(root.right,sum);
        return path;
    }
}

private int calcu(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if(root==null){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(root.val==sum){
        return 1 + calcu(root.left,sum-root.val)+calcu(root.right,sum-root.val);
    }
    else{
        return calcu(root.left,sum-root.val)+calcu(root.right,sum-root.val);
    }
}
}
```

explanation: `traverse` this tree and make every treeNode as root node, find target path under the premise continous.

Comment: You need to just `return 1` from here. Else you'll end up counting unwanted 0's. `else if(root.val==sum){         return 1 + calcu(root.left,sum-root.val)+calcu(root.right,sum-root.val);    }` .      
Imagine sum:8, a completely left skewed tree. 10 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> -2.
After finding the right path 5->3, the recursion will continue to find sum as 0, which is satisfied by 2, -2 and even this will be counted as another path.

Comment: @Bandi Kishore  no, `2-->-2 `will not be accepted by my program, because it is not  `continuous`. And there exist bug if just `return 1`.  `Imagine sum:0, a completely left skewed tree. 0 -> 5 -> -5-> 2 -> -2`, if just `return 1`, it will missing  `0->5->-5` and `0->5->-5->2->-2` . This is not what we want. And  `5->-5` and '2->-2' will not be accepted at this case about my code for it must begin with root 0 and must be `continuous`.

Comment: No, your code will still count 2 --> -2. Consider the same example 10 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 -> -2. When it reaches Node 3, it see's that `root.val==sum` is true, so it goes to `calcu()` with left Node that is 2 and sum as 0. Now again `root.val==sum` is false, so it goes to `calcu()` with leftNode that is -2 and sum as `(0-(Node 2)0 = -2`. Now again `root.val==sum` will become `-2 == -2` its true, so it returns 1. hence you'll end up counting 2 & -2. The special case of finding the sum "0" itself maybe handled in a different way, else this might mess up other cases.

Comment: @Bandi Kishore, this path is `5->3->2->-2` not `2->-2`, when current root is `5` there are two path which begin `root  5`, `5->3` and `5->3->2->-2`, when the current root is `2` the `2->-2` path will be processed. You can copy this code segment and test it, it have been already accepted by [the leetcode problem which OP refer](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-iii/)

Comment: Not sure how it got accepted, I guess they don't have a test case which handles this scenario. You check the output for the input 10 -> 5 ->3 -> 2-> -2 and sum as 8. It'll give an output as 2 Paths instead of one. Here is the output for the same code -  http://ideone.com/uim08g

Comment: @Bandi Kishore  it does have 2 paths instead of 1. `5 ->3` and  `5 ->3 -> 2-> -2 `

Comment: @cainiaofel Ah, now got it :) I wasn't considering  2 -> -2 as part of answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that it is also counting 10 - 2 = 8. where `10` is the topmost root node and `-2` is a bottom leaf. It ignores all the path in between.

I managed to solve it with a `tamperedSum` boolean.

```
public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum, boolean tamperedSum)  
{
    int path = 0;
    if(root.val == sum)
        path = 1;

    if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
        return path;

    if(root.left != null){
        path += pathSum(root.left, sum - root.val, true);
        if (!tamperedSum)
            path += pathSum(root.left, sum, false);
    }   
    if(root.right != null){
        path += pathSum(root.right, sum - root.val, true);
        if (!tamperedSum)
            path += pathSum(root.right, sum, false);
    }   
    return path;
}
```

The `tamperedSum` boolean is set to true when we have deducted values (of nodes) from the original sum which in this case is 8.

We would invoke it as:

```
pathSum(root, sum, false)
```

The idea is that if the sum has been *tampered* i.e a node value on the path has already been deducted, we are no longer allowed to pass it as-is to the branch below the node.

So, we set `tamperedSum` to `true` whenever we deduct the node value from the sum as: `sum - root.value`. After that, all nodes below it are not allowed to pass through the `sum` without deducting their node value from it.

Comment: When would it ever enter the `if(!tamperedSum)`? It'll be true for all scenarios.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the tamperedSum variable and the reason behind it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the tamperedSum variable and the reason behind it? Also how did you figure that the code initially was considering 10 and -2 as one path ?

Comment: Bandi, `tamperedSum` is set to false initially. It becomes true only when a node subtracts its value from original sum.

Comment: Deepti. Hope the edit clarifies it. I figured out the problem by debugging the program.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your solution is that you do not start from an initial sum, if you are in a new inner path.

so you should keep track of both the accomulated sum and the original sum as well when you move inner path.

find below a modified copy of your algorithm.

```
public static class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    boolean visitedAsRoot = false;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}

public static int pathSum(TreeNode root, int accomulate, int sum) {
    int path = 0;
    if (root.val == accomulate)
        return 1;
    else if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
        return 0;
    if (root.left != null) {
        path += pathSum(root.left, accomulate - root.val, sum);
        if (!root.left.visitedAsRoot) {
            root.left.visitedAsRoot = true;
            path += pathSum(root.left, sum, sum);
        }
    }
    if (root.right != null) {
        path += pathSum(root.right, accomulate - root.val, sum);
        if (!root.right.visitedAsRoot) {
            root.right.visitedAsRoot = true;
            path += pathSum(root.right, sum, sum);
        }
    }
    return path;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    TreeNode t1 = new TreeNode(3);
    TreeNode t2 = new TreeNode(-2);
    TreeNode t3 = new TreeNode(1);
    TreeNode t4 = new TreeNode(3);
    TreeNode t5 = new TreeNode(2);
    TreeNode t6 = new TreeNode(11);
    TreeNode t7 = new TreeNode(5);
    TreeNode t8 = new TreeNode(-3);
    TreeNode t9 = new TreeNode(10);

    t4.left = t1;
    t4.right = t2;

    t5.right = t3;

    t7.left = t4;
    t7.right = t5;

    t8.right = t6;

    t9.left = t7;
    t9.right = t8;

    System.out.println(pathSum(t9, 8, 8));
}
```

Comment: I don't think it would still work. Imagine the case where my tree is completely left skewed. The sum I need is 8. 10 -> 5 -> 5 -> 3. The output should be 1 but I guess this will give 2.

Comment: right, there was repeated visits for some nodes, I modified my answer.

Comment: Sorry, it still might not work :) Imagine the same completely left skewed tree. Sum = 8. 10 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 1. The output should be 1, I guess it would show 0. Because first it tries with 10, 5, 4, 3 and 1. When it couldn't form, it will mark 1 as visited and try. Again failed, so mark 3 as visited again try (but 1 is already marked, so it won't add it.) Now when it reached node 4 it'll now go for child nodes and try but these nodes are already visited (3,1).

Comment: no, it will work, the point is marking a node as visited means you will not start counting from it again as a starting node ;) .. but you will surely use it to accumulate for parent nodes. try it yourself it will work I already did :)